# build.gradle:Error while adding play-services dependencies for sdk Version 27

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am getting below error on dependency **implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'** after adding dependency    **implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'**

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion)

I want to use "PlaceAutocompleteFragment" which requires location dependency. I have tried adding location dependency using below method:

> File > Project Structure > Dependencies > + > search location

Got location version 12.0.2, which still throws above error. 
I know there are other questions with same error, but still I am not able to figure out the solution for my error.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.manish.abc"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Also pls let me know how to find the correct versions of dependecies applicable for api level I am using.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** :

In the hint you have :

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions **27.1.1, 26.1.0**. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and
>   **com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0** less... (Ctrl+F1)
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion)

You have to override each library with lower version showed in the hint, with the upper version,for example for `com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0` (seen in the hint)

Add `'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'` with the upper version **27.1.1** instead of **26.1.0** :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
```

And you repeat this until the warning goes

Comment: Latest version for 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location' is 15.0.1 as mentioned in official website. I have tried it with lower version too. but still same error.

Comment: I am not even using com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0, check build.gradle above. I am getting this error while adding location dependecy,but not on location line on appcompat line.

Comment: Yes but other libraries are using it, so you have to override it to get rid of the warning; Repeat the process until the warning goes

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the versions mismatch in dependencies.
Take the mouse cursor on to that line which is showing the error and check the version that is being expected that will pop up there.
Change to the recommended version and rebuild the project.

Comment: It doesn't suggest any version when I hover the mouse over the error line. Just the error message that I have posted above.

Comment: Try changing this classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'

Comment: getting below error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.jar
Required by:
    project :

Comment: Try updating the sdks

Comment: Did it already, updated sdk and android studio both. Getting similar kind of error in older project, hence created this new project to check, still getting this error.

Comment: If you are using  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0', change it to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' and give a try